# Query Data from Table with more than one billion rows

Tags: sql, indexing, rows

I have a simple table in SQL Server, looking like this:

```
id | Date | Value
```

I have a clustered index on `Date`, nonclustered index on `id`.

The table contains more than one billion rows.

I create a simple query that seem like this:

```
select * from table 
where id = x 
and date >= date1 and date < date2
```

Question: why it takes only less than one or max 3 seconds to find the data when I use for example date1 `01 sept 2013` and date2 `14 oct 2013`, but if I change date1 to `01 oct 2013` it takes over 50 seconds, and if I take `01 jan 2013` it takes again only less than 3 sec?

I have tried everything, I delete the cache and the SQL execution plan of the database, still the same ... did SQL Server forgot to set the index on this rows? I don't know what to do, it seems that it's working randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I would have an index on both (id, date). just an either-or won't benefit you. You need both in a single index.  Not clustered... your index that you already have by ID, just build that as (ID, Date)

Comment: Thank you, i will discuss this with my team cause updating the Table will take a while